# Кортеж кортежей в один кортеж или список

Tags: python, tuple

Как сделать из кортежа кортежей один кортеж или список?

Пробую так, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
x = (1.42, (1.5, 241.2), (52.2, 15.1), 52.1)

import itertools

print(tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

> 'float' object is not iterable

Потому что есть не только кортежи, но и простые числа с плавающей точкой. Как сделать в таком случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**способ 1:**

```
import numpy

x = (1.42, (1.5, 241.2), (52.2, 15.1), 52.1)

res = numpy.hstack(x).tolist()

print(res)
```

**способ 2:**

```
x = (1.42, (1.5, 241.2), (52.2, 15.1), 52.1)

res = []

for item in x:
    res += item if isinstance(item, tuple) else [item]

print(res)
```

Comment: выглядит зачётно, выглядит all right!

Comment: Использовать тяжеленный numpy ради таких простых задач :/

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def unpack(iterable: Iterable):  # Генератор
    for element in iterable:  # Перебираем все элементы коллекции
        if isinstance(element, Iterable):  # Если элемент является итерируемым
            yield from unpack(element)  # Распаковываем и его
        else:
            yield element  # Иначе возвращаем сам элемент

x = (1.42, (1.5, 241.2), (52.2, 15.1), 52.1)
unpacked = tuple(unpack(x))  # Приводим генератор к кортежу
print(unpacked)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def unpack(x):
    for a in x:
        try: yield from a
        except TypeError: yield a

print(list(unpack(x)))
```